# Without changing your current directory, create an empty file in another directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, directory, touch

Suppose my current working directory is:

```
    /Users/Directories
```

Under Directories, there are two separate directories called: firstname & last name. I move into the first name directory:

```
    $ cd firstname
```

and inside firstname, I want to create an empty file called test1.txt, so I type:

```
    $ touch test1.txt
```

This is where I am stuck: without leaving firstname, I want to create a file called test2.txt in the directory lastname. I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

```
    $ touch test2.txt../lastname
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply like that :

```
$ touch ../lastname/test2.txt
```

Note that instead of `touch`, you can use `>`¹

```
$ > ../lastname/test2.txt
```

You can also use an absolute path

```
$ > /Users/Directories/lastname/test2.txt
```

Beware that it would truncate files if they existed beforehand while `touch` would only update their access and last modification time.

---

<sup>¹ not in (t)csh nor fish though where you'd get an error, nor in zsh where it would run the `$NULLCMD`, redirecting an actual command that produces no output such as `true` or `printf` would work in any  shell.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to create more than one file in one command:

```
$ touch ../lastname/{test1.txt,test2.txt,test3.txt}
```

Or even here specifically:

```
$ touch ../lastname/test{1,2,3}.txt
```

That uses brace expansion, a feature introduced by the C-shell in the late 70s, and copied by many other shells including zsh, bash and fish. In some shells such as yash and some versions/builds of ksh, it is not enabled by default and you need `set -o braceexpand`. It  is not standard and shouldn't be used in `sh` scripts.

In the 90s, zsh extended it to support number ranges, so there (and in a few other shells that later copied it including ksh93 and bash), you can also do:

```
$ touch ../lastname/test{1..3}.txt
```

The equivalent syntax in the `rc` shells and its derivatives would be:

```
$ touch ../lastname/test^(1 2 3)^.txt
```